# Vista/win7 application volume control interface

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, audio

Which interface should I use to control the volume of my application on Vista or Windows 7?

The programming language doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A brief history of the windows audio API's](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/12/15/504158.aspx)

[There are several volume control points in Vista/W7](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2007/04/04/volume-in-windows-vista-part-2-types-of-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx)

[You probably want to use the ISimpleAudioVolume interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679138(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Huge thanks, I tried to use ISimpleAudioVolume before but for some reason it didnt worked, I'm sure I did something wrong with my header conversion, I'm using Delphi. Reading Larry's blog makes life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

This here article/library did it for me.  Import it and use ONELINER to set global application volume, which works with old style API that will work on XP and 7 as well.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/