# System volume control with Python, QT : PySide.phonon.Phonon.AudioOutputDevice

Tags: python, audio, qt4, volume, pyside

I would like to access (r/w) the Master Volume Control. I am currently using Windows 7.

There are "low-level" possibilities of controlling it:
 [Vista/win7 application volume control interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349112/vista-win7-application-volume-control-interface)

An older variant uses `ctypes` and Windows DLL:
 http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-March/004436.html
and probably derived work (requires `pymedia`):
 http:// code.google.com/p/palarm/downloads/detail?name=alarmwaveout.py&can=2&q=

For cross-platform this doesn't work anyway, so I thought of using a toolkit.
QT, pyQT or PySide came to mind, as I've been wanting to experiment with QT:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import sys
 from PySide.QtCore import *
 from PySide.QtGui import *

 import PySide.phonon

 app = QApplication(sys.argv)

 devicelist = PySide.phonon.Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioOutputDevices()
 print "Listing available audio output devices:"
 for device in devicelist:
  print " device:", device
  print "  description:", device.description()
  print "  index:", device.index()
  print "  isValid:", device.isValid()
  print "  name:", device.name()
  print "  property:", device.property( str( device.name() ) )
  print "  propertyNames:", device.propertyNames()
  print

 #~ audiodev = PySide.phonon.Phonon.AudioOutput()
 #~ slider = PySide.phonon.Phonon.VolumeSlider(audiodev)

 slider = PySide.phonon.Phonon.VolumeSlider( None )
 slider.setOrientation( Qt.Vertical )
 slider.show()

 app.exec_()
 sys.exit()
```

But I don't understand how to connect the VolumeSlider to an audio device (in this case, the Master ("Speakers") or default).

Comment: Here's the doc: http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/phonon/VolumeSlider.html#PySide.phonon.Phonon.VolumeSlider